# Patten matching done using lookbehind assertion. How to do it w/o using lookbehind in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am matching three patterns described below, they all are independent. Follow the hyperlinks to see demonstration in regex playground.

---

**Pattern**: `/(?<=^[^.]*\.[^.]*)\..*/g`, [matches everything beginning from second `.`](https://regex101.com/r/PssAM6/1).

---

**Pattern**: `/(?<=\.\d{2}).*/g`, for input characters that are `/[0-9.]/g` only, [matches everything beginning from 3rd digit after first `.`](https://regex101.com/r/0KduzX/2).

---

**Pattern**: `/(?<=\.\d{4}).*/g`, for input characters that are `/[0-9.]/g` only, [matches everything beginning from 5th digit after first `.`](https://regex101.com/r/GPnQSC/3).

---

I am not able to do this without using lookbehind in JS.

Comment: Can't you use capturing groups [like this](https://regex101.com/r/GPnQSC/4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do is use groups and grab the last group.

```js
let r1 = /(\.)[^.]*(\.)(.*)/g;

let m1 = r1.exec('..post dots match');
console.log(m1[m1.length-1]);

let r2 = /(\.\d{2})(.*)/g;

let m2 = r2.exec('.001234');
console.log(m2[m2.length-1]);

let r3 = /(\.\d{4})(.*)/g;
let m3 = r3.exec('.123400000');
console.log(m3[m3.length-1]);
```

Comment: Why did you do `/(\.)[^.]*(\.)(.*)/g`, is `/(^[^.]*\.[^.]*)(\..*)/g` not flexible enough?

Comment: That's just how I thought about it. You're correct that your version produces the same result.